# Multiple dependent async operations in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

We are doing some series of dependent async operations and those are dependent on each other in a NodeJS application.
Something like-

```
function (datas) {
  return await Promise.all(
    datas.map(async (data) => {
        //task1 task2 task3 are async functions
        const  response = {}
        response.id = data;

        const task1res = async task1(data).catch(err);
        if(task1res.error) return response;
        response.task1 = task1res;

        const task2res = async task2(task1res).catch(err);
        if(task2res.error) return response;
        response.task2 = task2res;

        const task3res = async task3(task2res).catch(err);
        if(task3res.error) return response;
        response.task3 = task3res;

        return response
    })
   ).catch(err);
}
```

So The output of this is an array containing response like-

```
[
        {
            id: “1”
            task1: task1res,
            task2: task2res,
            task3: task3res
        },
        {
            id: “2”
            task1: task1res,
            task2: task2res,
            task3: task3res
        },
        {
            id: “3”
            task1: task1res,
            task2: task2res,
            task3: task3res
        }  
    ]
```

As this all series of operations are async in nature, wanted to know if this is the right approach.

If one of the task will fail like example for the 1st data the task one failed-

```
[
        {
            id: “1”
            task1: “Error: fails”
        },
        {
            id: “2”
            task1: task1res,
            task2: task2res,
            task3: task3res
        },
        {
            id: “3”
            task1: task1res,
            task2: task2res,
            task3: task3res
        } 
    ]
```

What would be the fallback mechanism for this. How can we rerun the service for failed datas.

Comment: "To achieve this we are doing something like" — Please provide a real [mcve]. The code you have isn't even valid JS.

Comment: "wanted to know if this is the right approach" — That's a matter of opinion (and thus off-topic).

Comment: "If one of the task will fail like example" — Have you looked at [the documentation for Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)? It tells you what happens if any of the items in it reject.

Comment: If `bigTasks` is an array, `[bigTasks].map(/*...*/)` is incorrect. Just use `bigTasks.map(/*...*/)`.